# Статистическое обучение. Функция Y = f(x) и Y^=f(x)

Tags: статистика

Изучаю статистическое обучение по книге Introduction to statistical learning  и по ходу чтения возник вопрос. Что означает Y^ и f^ и для чего они вводятся? Не могут до конца понять их предназначение.

> In many situations, a set of inputs X are readily available, but the output Y cannot be easily obtained. In this setting, since the error term averages to zero, we can predict Y using
>   Y^=f^(x), (2.2)
>   where f^ represents our estimate for f , and Y^ represents the resulting prediction for Y . In this setting, f^ is often treated as a black box, in the sense that one is not typically concerned with the exact form of f^,provided that it yields accurate predictions for Y

Answer (score 0):

У вас изначально есть наборы точек {Xi} и {Yi}. По ним вы строите функцию f. Теперь вы берете точкe Хi. Подставляем ее в f и получаем некое значение Yi^. Оно, вообще-то говоря, отличается от значения Yi. Вот "крышечке" вам сообщает, что это не измеренное значение зависимой переменной, а "модельное" значение, полученное с помощью вашей построенной модели.

Вот как-то так.